# Running a DynamicModule outside the Notebook containg the DynamicModule

Tags: dynamic

Inspired by the "Using DynamicModule variables outside the DynamicModule", I'd like to have a hands-free approach to invoking a DynamicModule in a newly created Notebook.

One of the original answers was this:

```
DynamicModule[{x = True, nb = CreateDocument[{"hello"}]}, 
    Checkbox[Dynamic[x, (x = #; SetOptions[nb, Visible -> #]) &]]]
```

Replacing "hello" with a random input cell, we have:

```
DynamicModule[{x = True, nb = CreateDocument[{Cell["7+12", "Input"]}]}, 
    Checkbox[Dynamic[x, (x = #; SetOptions[nb, Visible -> #]) &]]]
```

So -- all I need to know how to do is evaluate that cell without having to click on it and press Shift-Enter.  I'm a bit of a noob, but if I can evaluate that 12+7, I'm sure I can evaluate the same cell containing an invocation of a DynamicModule.  Probably quite easy, I just don't know where to look.  But someone does--is it you?

Comment: Answer below ...

Comment: I'm not sure how is your question related to `DynamicModule`, the more that your answer does not mention it either.

Comment: I was assuming that what would work for 12+7 would also work for a symbol referencing a DynamicModule.  In other words, the question was really about how to evaluate the cell placed in the new notebook document with having to do it by hand (Shift-Enter, et.al.), whatever it's contents were...

Comment: Of course, this does work with a variable which references a DynamicModule.  Mine was just too big to post here.
Having said that ("it does work"), let me pull back and say "it almost works".  The Dynamic module I'm working with has a lot of interace elements in rows, columns, frames, etc...

Comment: Running the DynamicModule in the notebook where it is defined works perfectly, but when using the method discussed here, the interface element positioning is screwed up pretty badly.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question:

```
nb = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[12 + 7, "Input"]]; NotebookEvaluate[nb];
```